# Is it possible to remove the expand/collapse button from the jqGrid header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the jqGrid available at http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and I can't find a way to disable its expand/collapse button on the top right of the header. Anyone know if there's an option to do that?

I'd like to remove the thing circled in red:
[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes, there is an option for this: `hidegrid: false`

---

From the [jqGrid documentation wiki for Options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options):

> **hidegrid**
>
> boolean
>
> Enables or disables the show/hide grid button, which appears on the right side of the Caption layer. Takes effect only if the caption property is not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks Justin...must've overlooked it.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it took me awhile to find this one too :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to be totally accurate, it's not a colmodel option but an option. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options ;)

Comment: Good point, thanks for the catch! :) I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to colllapse all jqgrid on the page

```
elements = $('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv');
elements.each(function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
elements = $('div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv');
elements.each(function() { $(this).css("display", "none"); });
$('#JQGrid_pager').hide();
$('#rs_mJQGrid').hide();
```

Comment: That may work, but it is safer to use the option in case the underlying implementation were to change in a future release of jqGrid...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the main grids toggle button then you can set

```
hidegrid: false
```

If you are trying to disable or hide the subgrids expand and collapse button then use this on loadcomplete

```
jQuery("#GridTeableID").jqGrid('hideCol', "subgrid");
```