# jqGrid without header

Tags: jqgrid

I have tried to figure out how to disable the header for a jqGrid, so that the row containing the column names does not show. So far, I have come up with no solution. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see that the plugin gives you any options for this, but you could simply find and hide the container for the header.

```
...set up grid...

$('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').hide();
```

Answer (score 16):

Omitting the 'caption' property hides the header.

Very late I know, but for someone still wanting to know. This was found after looking through the source.

Comment: Like this much better than abusing JavaScript

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question was not about hiding the caption but how to hide the column's names. The accepted answer is the correct.

Comment: @PavlosPapanikolaou I agree with your comment.  After testing it on jsFiddle it no longer works.  Not too sure now whether I misunderstood the question in the first instance or whether there was a bug that had been fixed since.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
var grid = $("#GRID_NAME");
var gview = grid.parents("div.ui-jqgrid-view");
gview.children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why no-one has come up with the CSS solution yet...

```
.ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
  display:none !important;
}
```

You can scope it using a wrapper container for a single instance if you have other grids that shouldn't be affected.

Comment: IMHO this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me for jqGrid version 5.7

```
var tableId = document.getElementById('gridTablId').getAttribute("aria-labelledby");
document.querySelector("#" + tableId + " .ui-jqgrid-htable thead").style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an option for this: `hidegrid: false`

look at following [Is it possible to remove the expand/collapse button from the jqGrid header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015254/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-expand-collapse-button-from-the-jqgrid-header)

Comment: This does not solve my problem. According to the jqGrid documentation, the hidegrid option "Enables or disables the show/hide grid button, which appears on the right side of the Caption layer. Takes effect only if the caption property is not an empty string."