# JQGrid - Create grid without column names

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, names

I trying to create grid that contains rows with the following structure:

```
       item name, icon for delete, icon for sharing.
```

I'm trying to use JQGrid, and i can't find way to hide the column names (it's not necessary and i need only the data which comes from the server).

Do you know it it's possible to create JqGrid without displaying the column names?
Any other alternatives that can help?

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500477/jqgrid-without-header

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, it works.
Is it possible to apply this on specific grid and not on all grids?

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid without header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500477/jqgrid-without-header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out how to do it...

using firebug Iv'e found out that JQGrid name the grid div name as: `gview_gridame`. So using

```
$('#gview_MyGridName .ui-jqgrid-hdiv').hide();
```

will remove the header from specific grid.