# How to hide JqGrid column names

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid.
I want to hide the column names of the grid.
I gone through the documentation of Grid Options & ColModel. But found nothing.
Please find the JsFiddle Link - [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/564RP/25/)
I want to hide all column names such as Client, Inv No, Date, Amount, Tax, Total & Notes.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

```
enter code here
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqGrid without header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500477/jqgrid-without-header)

Comment: If one need to hide column headers only for one grid then one can use `$("#grid").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv").hide();`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14265456/315935) where column headers of subgrids will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I marked this as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500477/jqgrid-without-header) as it exactly answers your question, but the answer given there is simply to place the following line under your grid declaration:

```
$('.ui-jqgrid-hdiv').hide();
```